# optimizing pipeline execution for a set of assembly instructions

Tags: loops, assembly, cycle, pipeline

I have an instruction set that I am told to reorder the instructions to optimize the pipeline and draw the diagram of its execution. This is using a five-stage pipeline style (Fetch, Decode, Execute, Memory, Write Back). So the diagram would look something like this:

```
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
I0   F  D  E  M  W
I1      F  D  E  M  W
I2         F  D  E  M  W
...          etc
```

Below is an image of the instruction set. I drew in where I think some RAW dependencies are.

[image]

We are using static branch prediction with a not-taken assumption. Since we are dealing with static branch, is it correct to move the `Subtract R2, R2, #1` instruction right after the conditional? This way, it is in the branch delay slot and will always be executed no matter what. Is moving that Subtract instruction the only thing I can do? I can't really move or reorder the other instructions because of the data dependencies, can I? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

From the comments below, I think I was able to figure out a suitable pipeline. Let me know if this works.

```
     Load             R2, N
     Move             R4, #NUM1
     Clear            R3
LOOP Load             R5, (R4)
     Subtract         R2, R2, #1
     Add              R4, R4, #4
     Branch_if_[R2]>0 LOOP
     Add              R3, R3, R5 <-- Delayed Branch Slot
     Store            R3, SUM
```

I think this would work since it would eliminate the data dependencies (except for 1). For instance, look at the pipeline:

```
     Clock Cycles            1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13
Load             R2, N       F  D  E  M  W
Move             R4, #NUM1      F  D  E  M  W ------------
Clear            R3                F  D  E  M  W          RAW, fix w/ fwd
Load             R5, (R4)             F  D  E  M  W-------
Subtract         R2, R2, #1              F  D  E  M  W
Add              R4, R4, #4                 F  D  E  M  W
Branch_if_[R2]>0 LOOP                          F  D  E  M  W
Add              R3, R3, R5                       F  D  E  M  W
Store            R3, SUM                             F  D  E  M  W
```

This made it to where there is only one data dependency instead of three. Is this the best way to do it or is there an even better way?

**EDIT** I think I would need to move the `Add R4, R4, #4` instruction to the delayed branch slot. With the `Add R3, R3, R5` there, that creates a WAR anti-dependency. But then if I move them around, wouldn't I get another RAW dependency?

Comment: You can move the `move` (pun intended ;)) earlier so the load doesn't have to wait. You can also swap the two `add` instructions, since the second one can execute while the first one needs to wait.

Comment: If I understand correctly `store r3 sum` always runs at each iteration, is this desired?

Comment: Your loop body is so short that you need some software pipelining.

Comment: Software pipelining may not be the answer here because it's too advanced and require a lot of code to round the loop count to a optimal factor. But you should move `add r4 r4 #4` into the delay slot for sure.

Comment: @Jester I did not see that before. So if I move the `move` instruction to the very top, then that helps with one RAW dependency that I can see. I don't see how switching the two add instructions will help. Can you explain that to me a bit further? Thanks.

Comment: Also, was me moving `Subtract` outside the loop the right thing to do? I remember reading that for static branch prediction to move the instruction right before the conditional to the delayed branch slot.

Comment: As you have written, the first `add` needs the `r5` from the previous `load` so would need to wait. If you swap them, the other `add` can execute in that slot.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. So just move the `move` to the top, switch the `add` statements, and move the `subtract` to the delayed branch slot?

Comment: @user3528438 How come I would move `Add R4, R4, #4` into the delayed branch slot and not `Subtract R2, R2, #1`? Would that solve the data dependency between that and `Move R4, #NUM1`?

Comment: I edited my post to include what I think a suitable solution would be. Does this look good?

Comment: @GenericUser01 Assuming the pipelining works as in regular processors -  no, you cannot move the subtract. The branch is dependent on the subtract and if it's after the branch, it won't ever affect it. Also you cannot move the add after the subtract since then the branch will work based on the addition, not the subtraction.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Isn't the point of moving an instruction to the delayed branch slot that it will always still be executed even if the branch isn't taken? Also, how come we can't move the add? The branch instruction is looking only at `R2` so why would moving the add that deals with other registers affect the branch?

Comment: You haven't explained how this CPU would work, so I have no idea what a delayed slot would be. In regular pipelines the instructions are not run if the branch is taken. And yes, if there is an instruction to check for R2 then you can reorder them.

Comment: I thought I explained it when I mentioned how this is a five-stage pipeline that uses static branch prediction with a not-taken assumption. So since this branch instruction is checking for `R2`, then I can move one of the add instructions to the delayed branch slot since you yourself said I can reorder them. The add instruction has nothing to do with `R2` and won't affect that expression. A delayed branch slot is only used for optimization. It moves 1 instruction before the loop conditional to the delayed branch slot and though it looks as if it is outside the loop, it will always be executed.